# Autosys on every monday and first day of month

Tags: unix, jobs, autosys

I need to configure a autosys schedule which should run on every monday and 1st of every month. Is it possible to do in single JIL file.

I have used `days_of_week: mo`  and what is the config used for date.

Is it possible to write a `OR` condition to trigger the job on either 1st or monday.

Comment: run_calendar:  create_a_calender_and_pass_the_name_here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say just create a calendar with those requirements, you can also do that as extended calendar so you don't have to update the regular calendar ever.
Choice is yours :)